# Add id name to each part of the css when making a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

so I never formally learned how make a nav menu using specific names for the ul and the child li. I created a menu [on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBebk) which is finished. Except I need to give all the css a specific name.

So right now for example I have.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>
  Small
  <ul>
      <li>link here</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

example css

```
#nav {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

ul li {
  width:72px;
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

How would I go about adding #nav before each css item. So if I put #nav li {code} in the css and put id="#nav" in the < li > then the code doesn't work anymore.

TLDT: I want each part of my css to have a specific id so the ul li code doesn't effect the other parts of my website.

Comment: Giving ID's to your DOM is a code smell. The ID of a DOM element should reflect some actual ID that the server or localStorage should map to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep #nav on the ul, and use the CSS selector: `#nav > li` which will select any immediate `li` children of `#nav` and ignore anything beyond that.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jubJI

Comment: How would I do the same method for the other part of my code. So below what you have changed. Would ul li ul { become #nav > ul > li > ul {?

Comment: Yep, you can do that! You might have to go through and clean some stuff up. For example if you want ALL li's that are children / grandchildren of #nav to have a color of black, you would do #nav li { color: black}

Comment: @AndrewH - Please see my post for an explanation on how to create CSS Selectors.  When ever you apply an ID to an element, you can reference that element by its element type, for example just typing ul in the css.  Or you can type simply #nav which references the exact same element.

Answer (score 2):

An additional answer to MathiasaurusRex's answer.  It seems to me like you are struggling with understanding how to write selectors properly.  The below might help.

Assuming this HTML structure...

```html
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then the following CSS Selectors ALL target the exact same element.

```css
#nav { /*code*/ }
ul { /*code*/ }
ul#nav { /*code*/ }
```

All three of the above target the same element, but with different specificity.  Especially when used in chain with other selectors...  For example...

```css
ul li { /* code */ }
```

The code in the above selector applies to ANY `<li>` element that is a descendant of ANY `<ul>` element.

```css
#nav li { /* code */ }
```

The code in the above selector applies to ANY `<li>` element that is a descendant of ANY element that ALSO has an ID of "nav".  In the above HTML sample, that also happens to be the `<ul>` element.

```css
ul#nav li { /* code */ }
```

The above selector is essentially the same as the second selector above it, but it adds further specificity in that the ID HAS to be on a `<ul>` element.  If the ID "nav" was on a different element the code would not apply.

---

Also note that ID's should really only be used ONCE per page.  If you have something that may repeat, then use a class instead.  `class="name"` and `.name`

Answer (score 0):

ids are used as unique selectors - that is, there can be only one of any given id per page. For this, you should instead use give them a [class](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp) with `class='className'` and apply styling to them with `.className {Code;}`.